# Why didn't Moxy initialize the Presenter (Kotlin, Android)

Tags: android, kotlin

I got error that mPresenter has not been initialized. I didn't understand WHY?
I got this error when I use Kotlin but if I use JAVA everything is fine
Here is my code

View

```
@StateStrategyType(value = AddToEndStrategy::class)
interface IHelloWorldView : MvpView {
    fun showMessage(message: Int)
}
```

Presenter

```
@InjectViewState
class HelloWorldPresenter : MvpPresenter<IHelloWorldView>() {
    fun show() = viewState.showMessage(R.string.message)
}
```

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), IHelloWorldView {

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var mPresenter: HelloWorldPresenter

    lateinit var mText: TextView
    lateinit var mButton: Button

    override fun showMessage(message: Int) {
        mText.setText(message)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mText = findViewById(R.id.text)
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button)
        mButton.setOnClickListener {
            mPresenter.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are creating presenter as uninitialized via `lateinit`. This can be works `var mPresenter = HelloWorldPresenter()`

Comment: I assume you are missing `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'`?

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to init it like in JAVA `Foo foo = new Foo();`

It seems like you only created a variable

```
class MainActivity : MvpAppCompatActivity(), IHelloWorldView {

    @InjectPresenter
    lateinit var mPresenter: HelloWorldPresenter
    //initialisation

    @ProvidePresenterTag(presenterClass = HelloWorldPresenter::class, type =PresenterType.GLOBAL)
    fun providemPresenter() = HelloWorldPresenter()
    fun mPresenter() = HelloWorldPresenter()

    lateinit var mText: TextView
    lateinit var mButton: Button

    override fun showMessage(message: Int) {
        mText.setText(message)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        mText = findViewById(R.id.text)
        mButton = findViewById(R.id.button)
        mButton.setOnClickListener {
            mPresenter.show()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**type = PresenterType.GLOBAL** - do not exist (at least in kotlin)